# Populate of circles in database

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers, openstreetmap

How to store in a database (mysql ou postgresql) circles (or other shapes such as polygons, rectangles, markers) drawn with Openlayers/Openstreemap ?
I would like also to define before a schema compatible with google maps api.

OpenGis maybe ?

Comment: For a circle, all you need is the center and radius (and any other properties you want to replicate, like possibly fillColor, fillOpacity, ...).  Polygons and Polylines are more complicated, you need to save all the vertices (of all the paths).

Comment: What about the schema ? what do you advice ?